# Why I can call StringFromCLSID even without the calling of CoInitializeEx before?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, com

I am learning COM through C++. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909149.aspx):

> Applications **are required** to use CoInitializeEx before they make any
>   other COM library calls *except for memory allocation functions*.

*The memory allocation functions* is `CoTaskMemAlloc` and `CoTaskMemFree` in my opinion.

But I see, my "Hello World" works fine with and without the `CoInitializeEx` and `CoUninitialize` functions calling. In my code I use the `StringFromCLSID` function which is declared in the `combaseapi.h` header. So, *it is a COM function in my opinion*. My code:

```
/* entry_point.cpp */
#include "Tools.h"
#include <objbase.h>

int main(){
  HRESULT hr = ::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
  if (FAILED(hr)){
    trace("Can't initialize COM for using in the current thread.");
    keep_window_opened();
    return 1;
  }
  // {D434CF7D-2CDD-457A-A4EF-5822D629CE83}
  static const CLSID clsid =
  { 0xd434cf7d, 0x2cdd, 0x457a, { 
    0xa4, 0xef, 0x58, 0x22, 0xd6, 0x29, 0xce, 0x83 } };

  const size_t SIZE = 39;
  wchar_t* wch = nullptr;
  hr = ::StringFromCLSID(clsid, &wch);
  if (FAILED(hr)){
    trace("Can't convert CLSID to wchar_t array.");
  }
  else{
    trace("CLSID converted to wchar_t array.");
    char mch[SIZE];
    size_t count = 0;
    int result = ::wcstombs_s(&count, mch, wch, SIZE);
    if (result){
      trace("Can't convert wchar_t array to char array.");
    }
    else{
      trace(mch);
    }
    ::CoTaskMemFree(wch);
  }
  ::CoUninitialize();

  keep_window_opened();
  return 0;
}
```

If I remove the calls of `CoInitializeEx` and `CoUninitialize` functions, then my code works still. I expected it will not work...

Why `StringFromCLSID` work even without the calling of `CoInitializeEx` before?

Thank you.

Comment: This might sound a bit pedantic but I think it's important: you are best served by always obeying specifications. That rule says Microsoft is allowed to make `StringFromCLSID` crash your program if `CoInitializeEx` has not been called first; the fact that it hasn't happened to you is *immaterial*. In programming language circles this is called "undefined behavior". What happens instead is that Microsoft spends thousands of hours adding otherwise superfluous code, and giving up on performance enhancements, because of having to protect programs that don't obey specifications.

Comment: @Bush: The documentation you linked to is for the **Windows Mobile** version of `CoInitializeEx()`. The **desktop** version of `CoInitializeEx()` is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx) instead, and has different verbage than the mobile version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why StringFromCLSID work even without the calling of CoInitializeEx before?

The key information is stated right in the documentation.

[`CoInitializeEx` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx):

> You need to initialize the COM library on a thread before you call any of the library functions **except ... the memory allocation functions**. Otherwise, the COM function will return CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED.

[`StringFromCLSID` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683917.aspx):

> StringFromCLSID calls the [StringFromGUID2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683893.aspx) function to convert a globally unique identifier (GUID) into a string of printable characters.
>
> **The caller is responsible for freeing the memory allocated for the string by calling the [CoTaskMemFree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680722.aspx) function**.

[`StringFromCLSID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683917.aspx) returns a dynamically allocated string.  We can infer from the highlighted sentence above that the memory is allocated using [`CoTaskMemAlloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692727.aspx) - which is explicitly documentated as not requiring [`CoInitializeEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx).

[`StringFromGUID2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683893.aspx) formats [`GUID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931.aspx) data into a caller-specified memory block.  Formatting a string does not require COM functionality. The [`wsprintfW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550.aspx), [`StringCbPrintfW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647510.aspx), or other equivalent function would suffice.  So [`CoInitializeEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx) should not be required for [`StringFromGUID2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683893.aspx), even though this is not explicitly documented.  I think it would be pretty short-sighted for Microsoft to not use one of their many available string formatting functions to implement [`StringFromGUID2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683893.aspx). So I think it should be safe to say that [`CoInitializeEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx) is not a requirement for this (unless Microsoft says otherwise).

The [`GUID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931.aspx) structure simply contains a few numbers and bytes.  *Declaring and using* a [`GUID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931.aspx) is not dependent on the COM library.  You can freely use a [`GUID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931.aspx) in your code all you want without touching COM at all - unless you want to generate a new [`GUID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931.aspx), in which case the [`CoInitializeEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx) requirement for [`CoCreateGUID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688568.aspx) is blurry as [`CoCreateGUID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688568.aspx) is in the COM library but is explicitly documented as simply calling [`UuidCreate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205.aspx), which is in the RPC library instead.

So that is why you can call [`StringFromCLSID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683917.aspx) without calling [`CoInitializeEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279.aspx) first.  A [`GUID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931.aspx) on its own does not require COM initialization. The string is being allocated with a memory function that does not require COM initialization.  And the string is being formatted in a manner that *most likely* does not require COM initialization.

Answer (score 4):

`StringFromCLSID` is basically a printout of GUID value (bytes) into string, then formatting it nicely with hyphens and braces. There is nothing else involved and hence COM initialization is not really needed for this call to succeed.

You have to do `CoInitialize`/`CoInitializeEx` to be safe, but not doing it you don't necessarily hit a problem right away.

Comment: MSDN recommends to use `CoInitializeEx` instead of `CoInitialize`: *"New applications should call `CoInitializeEx` instead of `CoInitialize`."*

Comment: This is corrrect, however `CoInitialize` call is simply equal to `CoInitializeEx` call with `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED` argument.